# Unable to recieve values in post request using react and php

Tags: php, reactjs, authentication

I created a signup system using React and PHP.
Now I am trying to login the user, but the values are not being received in PHP although I am using the same approach in the login as in the signup.
In Chrome I am receiving that my request has been redirected, but in Firefox, I get an error because my data is empty.

When I was doing the signup, I got the data using ( **file_get_contents("php://input", true))** ). However, now in the login, it is not giving me any data.

**This is my fetch hook**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function useFetch(url, options) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!url) return;
        setLoading(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            (async function fetchData() {
                try {
                    const response = await fetch(url, options);
                    if(!response.ok) throw new Error();
                    const data = await response.json();
                    setData(data);
                    setLoading(false)
                } catch(e) {
                    setLoading(false)
                    setError(e.message);
                }
            })()
        }, 3000);;
    }, [url])
    return [data, loading, error];
}

export default useFetch
```

**This is my login component**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import classes from '../../assets/styles/Main.module.css'
import useFetch from '../../hooks/useFetch';
function Login() {
    const [userInputs, setUserInputs] = useState({
        "username": "nadim",
        "email": "nadim.aa@hotmail.com",
        })
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);
    const [data, loading, error] = useFetch(url,  {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(userInputs),
        mode: "no-cors",
    });

    const submitHandler = () => {
        setUrl("http://localhost/whatsinit/api/user");
    }
    console.log(data, loading, error);
    return (
        <div className={classes.login}>
            <h2>Login to your account</h2>
            <input className={classes.login_username} type='text' placeholder='Username or email'/>
            <input className={classes.singup_password} type='password' placeholder='Password'/>
            <button onClick={submitHandler} className={classes.register_button}>login</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

**This is my PHP**

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
include_once '../../config/Database.php';

class User {
    private $table = 'users';
    private $connection;
    private $username;
    public function __construct($connection, $user_inputs) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        if(!is_null($user_inputs)) {
            $this->username = $user_inputs['username'];
            $this->email = $user_inputs['email'];
        }
    }
    public function readUser() {
        try {
            $command = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE (username = ? OR email = ?);";
            $stmt = $this->connection->stmt_init();
            $stmt->prepare($command);
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $this->username, $this->email);
            if(!$stmt->execute()) {
                throw new Exception("Could not get user");
            }
            $response = $stmt->get_result();
            return $response;
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            echo json_encode($th->getMessage());
        }
        $this->connection->close();
    }
}

$database = new Database();
$connection = $database->connect();
$user = new User($connection, json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input", true)));

try {
    $result = $user->readUser();
    $nums = $result->num_rows;
    $json_items = array();
    if($nums) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            extract($row);
            array_push($json_items, $row);
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Not Registered!");
    }
    echo json_encode($json_items);
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
    echo json_encode($th->getMessage());
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `no-cors`. https://evertpot.com/no-cors/

Comment: @Evert Thank you for the information about no-cors. However the problem was logic problem. I was trying to POST to a file inside a folder named 'api'. Apparently these technologies know the drill and won't allow a POST to an API